# Graphics and Icon on Android apps running under Arc Welder or Bluestacks are corrupted

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

[Error icon on Android apps when running under Arc Welder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KyzQ.png)

The above is the icon I got when I run Android apps under Arc Welder or Bluestacks.

The original icon is like the below:

[Original icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9gk1.png)

Why is this happen? and how can I solve it?

Comment: If your app is already present on playstore it might have updated it. Try deploying by increment package version number. If problem still persists check your path of image if its entered correct.

Comment: The apps is the latest version.  Also, it's not just one apps.  All apps using Arc Welder or Bluestacks have the same issue. Originally I guess it is Bluestacks issue, but now as Arc Welder also has the same issue, I think it is a general problem when running Android apps on Windows.  I have tried using Linux version of Chrome and Arc Welder, it runs prefectly!!!

Comment: ok if its working perfectly on your phone then it wont be coding error at your end recently with BlueStack update even our app wasnt opening properly. Though we have raised a support ticket I have yet to receive a reply from bluestack team.

Comment: Thanks! As running apps with Arc Welder also has the same issue, I think it is not related to solely Bluestacks or Arc Welder.  But I can't identify is it a problem hiding deeper on the Windows side as it only happens in Windows.

Comment: For us controls not showing or working properly was the issue but replacing image itself I dont think bluestack would do that. you can search inside your res folder if that image asset is present. If its there then you might have added it as icon for a different resolution because of which you might be seeing that.

Comment: In fact, it's all graphics in the apps has that issue.  Every image showing in the apps is flipped diagonally, even some images download from the network and showing in the apps.  Should it be a driver issue?  I'm using Intel graphics card.

Comment: I just found a post related to Bluestacks... someone also figured out the same issue:  https://m.reddit.com/r/BlueStacks/comments/3vwjpd/bluestacks_mirroring_error/

Comment: It seems that Bluestacks has a solution here, but I don't know how similar fix can be applied to ArcWelder: http://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/206725196-How-to-fix-distorted-mirrored-images-issue-